# Java Generics: convert List<TypeA> to List<TypeB>

Tags: java, generics

this is a basic question, i guess. However, coming from C++ this is not as easy as i expected. Please consider the following code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

final class TestClass {

    public class Foo {
        int myInt;
        float myFloat;
    }

    public class Bar {
        int myInt;
        float myFloat;
    }

    private static Bar toBar(Foo in) {
        Bar out = new Bar();
        out.myInt = in.myInt;
        out.myFloat = in.myFloat;
        return out;
    }

    public static <InT, OutT> List<OutT> toBar(List<InT> in) {
        List<OutT> out = new ArrayList<>(in.size());
        for (InT inElement: in) {
            out.add(toBar(inElement));
        }
        return out;
    }
}
```

This gives me an error: " error: no suitable method found for toBar(InT)".

I have a lot of collections, that need to be converted from `List<TypeA1>` to `List<TypeB1>`, `List<TypeA2>` to `List<TypeB2>`. To reduce code, i wanted to extract the list iteration in a Java Generic, while doing the element conversion in a concrete implementation. Any ideas, how to do this? Unfortunately, third-party libs are not allowed.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: First toBar method takes a Foo. InT is not necessarily a Foo

Comment: ... and returns a `Bar`, which is not necessarily a `OutT`.

Comment: Why not just use `public static List<Bar> toBar(List<Foo> in) {` !?

Comment: @luk2302 OP said they want this to be generic as they have lists of many different types

Answer (score 8):

Your `static` method doesn't pass compilation because the `toBar` method you are calling expects a `Foo` argument, not a generic type parameter that can be anything.

You don't need a method to do the conversion. You can achieve the same with a relatively short `Stream` pipeline:

```
List<Foo> foos = ...
List<Bar> bars = foos.stream().map(TestClass::toBar).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Of course, if you must, you can wrap this in a method, but you'll have to pass a `Function` that tells the method how to convert an element of the first `List` to an element of the second `List`:

```
public static <InT, OutT> List<OutT> convert(List<InT> in, Function<InT,OutT> converter) {
    return in.stream().map(converter).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

And you call it with:

```
List<Foo> foos = ...
List<Bar> bars = convert(foos,TestClass::toBar);
```

Answer (score 3):

Despite the syntactical similarity, C++ templates and Java generics are very different.

In C++, the templates are instantiated at compile time when the templates are used. So if I write `toBar(listOfFoos)`, the compiler starts compiling the `toBar(List<Foo>)` method. At this point it knows that it needs to call `toBar(Foo)`. If I write `toBar(listOfBazs)` a few lines later, it compiles an additional `toBar(List<Baz>)` method, in which an entirely different method can be called.

In Java, on the other hand, the method is compiled only once. At compile time it must be clear which method is to be called. And in your case, it cannot find a matching method.

One option would be to pass the method as a parameter:

```
 public static <InT, OutT> List<OutT> toBar(List<InT> in, Function<InT, OutT> fn) {
    List<OutT> out = new ArrayList<>(in.size());
    for (InT inElement: in) {
        out.add(fn.apply(inElement));
    }
    return out;
}
```

and call it with

```
result = toBar(listOfFoos, TestClass::toBar);
```

Or you use a stream:

```
result = listOfFoos.stream()
                   .map(TestClass::toBar)
                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```